# Picking between Redisson and Lettuce for Redis with clustered-setup

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, lettuce, redisson, leader-election

I am considering [Lettuce](https://lettuce.io/) and [Redisson](https://redisson.org/) java clients for use in my application server *(to connect to Redis)*. I haven't been able to find a proper comparison of the two from people who have tried them both or one of them in a single common place. The only detailed comparison I have seen is [here](https://redisson.org/lettuce-replacement-why-redisson-is-the-best-lettuce-alternative.html) and a few other links all published by ***Redisson*** itself. The other link I found was this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62338409/lettuce-or-redisson) post which has not been received very well.

I would like to hear from people who have actually consumed both or either of the clients, their experiences/use-cases and what were the pros and/or cons. I currently have a clustered Redis setup and I am using Lettuce. ***Lettuce*** achieves what I want. However it had some pain points with discovering new nodes in the cluster upon failover. I raised this in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63258239/is-there-a-way-to-auto-discover-new-cluster-node-ip-in-redis-cluster-with-lettuc?noredirect=1#comment111892767_63258239) and was able to resolve it as explained in the answer. In the positive side I find the Lettuce documentation much cleaner and easier to follow compared to that of Redisson's.

I am mainly considering a move to ***Redisson*** because I am hoping to use Redisson's implementation of [RedLock by Redis](https://redis.io/topics/distlock) for the purposes of *Leader election* between multiple instances of my app-server. Lettuce does not provide an implementation of it. Hence, the only option out-of-box is Redisson. In this case I would also have to get rid of Lettuce completely and Redisson alone. How is Redissons support for Redis cluster deployments. I was wondering does Redisson have reported/pending issues with cluster node discovery on failover *(I haven't seen any in their [repo](https://github.com/redisson))*. I have also read concerns over the library being bulky and not as lightweight as Lettuce is.

Given the above concerns and the knowledge I already have I would like to know comments about the use of both of these clients to help me with making a decision.

Thank you

Comment: General "*share your experience*" type of questions are ill suited for SO format and thus deemed out of scope.

Comment: But can I get a comparative analysis between the clients in order to help me with a decision. I have outlined by use case and the expectation. I can rephrase it

Comment: I have not tried the auto-rediscovery one since we're using a managed Redis offered by a cloud platform, thus don't need to worry about it. Though I'm pretty certain that  Redisson offers it since it's production ready client used by lots of companies I know. It can be a drop-in replacement for Lettuce and works well except a few edge cases, like the Redis INFO command, Lettuce implements it while Redisson doesn't

Comment: @AwesomeHunter I'm afraid you're mistaken here. INFO command can be executed on every Redis node. Like this:  RedisSingle nodes = redisson.getRedisNodes(RedisNodes.SINGLE);
RedisMaster node = nodes.getInstance();

Map<String, String> allResponse = node.info(RedisNode.InfoSection.ALL);

Comment: You can emulate a compareAndSet by providing a Redis script (search for compare and set + redis) that is executed against your key. Together with TTL is what I use. I also would like to know if redisson is really a good idea as it hides a lot of the implementation stuff and redis is not particular rocket science. Also it is a commercial company meaning who knows if they screw with the community version's quality (burned by another company back in the days, so redisson is not to blame but my experience). I settled with lettuce and would upgrade if I would need it but not needed it... .